# Dispatch Events in windows phone

Tags: events, windows-phone-7

I am not sure if this question has been asked before in stack overflow but anyways the question is,

> Is there something that is equivalent to `dispatchKeyEvent` or a `dispatchTouchEvent` in windows phone development?

a dispatchKeyEvent or a dispatchTouchEvent would dispatch a keyin event or a touch event programmatically in an android application.( All we need to do is to construct the KeyEvent object and pass it on to the dispatchKeyEvent function along with the keycode) .

If this is something that exists in android then is there a similar API available for windows phone development?

Answer (score 0):

In .NET you can [Raise a Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). And in your case, you would be raising the `Tap` event (if it's for a tap). It's not really related to Windows Phone at all.

The [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) have support for various other gestures (such as flick, drag, etc.).

Regardless, it's somewhat bad programming having to raise a UI event yourself, rather than simply letting the UI event call a conventional method, that you also could call from any other place in the code, without supplying any event parameters.

Comment: I think I am getting a little confused here. I am talking about events like a keyEvent or a touch event. I think silverlight supports gestures to handle it and not to raise it. I did not find support in silverlight for raising a keyboard event.

Comment: That's because the [KeyEventArgs have no constructors defined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5746279/95309), so you can't create a custom `KeyEventArgs`. The big question is why you would need to do this, as I pointed out, it's bad practise.

Comment: Ok. If its a bad practice then can you give me an instance as to why android has it?

Comment: .NET have the ability to invoke events as well, as I pointed out. That doesn't change it's bad practise to use, **also** on Android. Any decent Java programmer would frown upon doing manual event invokes, rather than abstracting the code out in a separate class. (And Android's API is terrible, but that's another story)